# Entities passed to the choice field must be managed. Can't pass a Item to a array field

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I get the following error in Symfony 2 when trying to open a form using the bellow action.

> Entities passed to the choice field must be managed. Maybe persist
>   them in the entity manager? 500 Internal Server Error -
>   RuntimeException

How can I persist a Entity that's dependent on another one before even having submitted the form, what's the correct method for doing this?
I'm trying to store the items passed to the form by using:

```
$imoved = new ItemMoved();
$imoved->setItem($Item);
$entity->setItems(array($imoved));
```

Controller Action

```
/**
 * Displays a form to create a new MovementNotification entity.
 *
 * @Route("/new/{id}", name="am_movementnotification__new")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function newAction($id)
{
    $entity = new MovementNotification();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $Item = $em->getRepository("FarAssetManagerBundle:Item")->find($id+0);

    if (!$Item) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Item entity. ' . $id );
    }

    $token = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken();
    if ($token != null ) {
        $user = $token->getUser();
        if (!is_object($user)) {
            // FIXME take some action in this case;
            $user = 0;
        } else {
            $user = $user->getId();
        }
    } else {
        $user = 0;
    }

    $entity->setUser($user);
    $imoved = new ItemMoved();
    $imoved->setItem($Item);
    $entity->setItems(array($imoved));
    $entity->setDatein(new \DateTime("now"));
    //$entity->setLocation($Item->getLocation());
    $entity->setState((string) new OpenState());
    //$entity->setState($Item->getState());

    $form   = $this->createCreateForm($entity);

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    );
}
```

Entity

```
<?php

namespace Far\AssetManagerBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * MovementNotification
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="far_assetmanager_movement_notification")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Far\AssetManagerBundle\Entity\MovementNotificationRepository")
 */
class MovementNotification
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \Far\AssetManagerBundle\Entity\ItemMoved
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Far\AssetManagerBundle\Entity\ItemMoved", mappedBy="MovementNotification", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({@ORM\JoinColumn(name="movement_notification_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
     */
    private $items;

    /**
     * @var \Far\AssetManagerBundle\Entity\Location
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Far\AssetManagerBundle\Entity\Location")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="location_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $location;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="state", type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $state;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="descricao", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $descricao;

    /**
     * @var \Far\AssetManagerBundle\Entity\State
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Far\AssetManagerBundle\Entity\State")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="state_object_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $stateObject;

    /**
     * @var \Far\StockBundle\Entity\User
     *
     * in order to avoid a hard dependency on a security
     * module i-ll just leave this has an int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @var \Far\AssetManagerBundle\Entity\MovementNotification
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Far\AssetManagerBundle\Entity\MovementNotification")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     * })
     */
    private $parent;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="datein", type="datetime")
     */
    private $datein;

    /**
     * @var \Far\AssetManagerBundle\Entity\TransportNotice
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Far\AssetManagerBundle\Entity\TransportNotice")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="transport_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     * })
     */
    private $transport;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set item
     *
     * @param integer $item
     *
     * @return MovementNotification
     */
    public function setItems($items)
    {
        $this->items = $items;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get item
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getItems()
    {
        return $this->items;
    }

    /**
     * Set location
     *
     * @param Location $location
     *
     * @return MovementNotification
     */
    public function setLocation($location)
    {
        $this->location = $location;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get location
     *
     * @return Location
     */
    public function getLocation()
    {
        return $this->location;
    }

    /**
     * Set state
     *
     * @param string $state
     *
     * @return MovementNotification
     */
    public function setState($state)
    {
        $this->state = $state;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get state
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getState()
    {
        return $this->state;
    }

    /**
     * Set descricao
     *
     * @param string $descricao
     *
     * @return MovementNotification
     */
    public function setDescricao($descricao)
    {
        $this->descricao = $descricao;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get descricao
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescricao()
    {
        return $this->descricao;
    }

    /**
     * Set stateObject
     *
     * @param integer $stateObject
     *
     * @return MovementNotification
     */
    public function setStateObject($stateObject)
    {
        $this->stateObject = $stateObject;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get stateObject
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getStateObject()
    {
        return $this->stateObject;
    }

    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param integer $user
     *
     * @return MovementNotification
     */
    public function setUser($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * Set parent
     *
     * @param integer $parent
     *
     * @return MovementNotification
     */
    public function setParent($parent)
    {
        $this->parent = $parent;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get parent
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return $this->parent;
    }

    /**
     * Set datein
     *
     * @param \DateTime $datein
     *
     * @return MovementNotification
     */
    public function setDatein($datein)
    {
        $this->datein = $datein;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get datein
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDatein()
    {
        return $this->datein;
    }

    /**
     * Set transport
     *
     * @param integer $transport
     *
     * @return MovementNotification
     */
    public function setTransport($transport)
    {
        $this->transport = $transport;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get transport
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getTransport()
    {
        return $this->transport;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return "N. Movimento: " . $this->getId();
    }
}


<?php

namespace Far\AssetManagerBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * ItemMoved
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="far_assetmanager_movement_notification_item")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ItemMoved
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * Set id
     *
     * @param integer $id
     * @return ItemMoved
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @var \Far\AssetManagerBundle\Entity\Item
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Far\AssetManagerBundle\Entity\Item", inversedBy="items",cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="item_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $Item;

    public function setItem($item)
    {
        $this->Item = $item;
    }

    public function getItem()
    {
        return $this->Item;
    }

    /**
     * @var \Far\AssetManagerBundle\Entity\MovementNotification
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Far\AssetManagerBundle\Entity\MovementNotification")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="movement_notification_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     * })
     */
    private $MovementNotification;

    public function setMovementNotification($mn)
    {
        $this->MovementNotification = $mn;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getMovementNotification()
    {
        return $this->MovementNotification;
    }

    function __toString() {
        return $this->getItem()->getDescription() . " " . $this->getMovementNotification()->getId();
    }
}
```

Form Type MovementNotification

```
<?php

namespace Far\AssetManagerBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Far\AssetManagerBundle\Entity\LocationRepository;
use Far\AssetManagerBundle\Entity\StateRepository;

class MovementNotificationType extends AbstractType
{

    public function __construct($em, array $options = null)
    {
        $this->em = $em;

        if ($options != null && isset($options['type'])) {
            $this->type = $options['type'];
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('descricao','textarea', array('attr' => array("cols" => 40 , "rows" => 10)))
            ->add('user', 'hidden')
            ->add('datein')
            ->add('items', 'collection', 
                array(
                    'type' =>
                    new ItemMovedType(
                            $this->em
                    ),
                    'allow_add' => false,
                    'allow_delete' => false,
                    'prototype' => false
                    )
                )
            ->add('location', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'FarAssetManagerBundle:Location',
                'query_builder' => function (LocationRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('l')
                        ->orderBy('l.description', 'ASC');
                },
                'choice_label' => 'Description',
            ))
            ->add('state', 'hidden')
            ->add('stateObject', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'FarAssetManagerBundle:State',
                'query_builder' => function (StateRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('st')
                        ->orderBy('st.description', 'ASC');
                },
                'choice_label' => 'Description',
            ))
            ->add('parent', 'hidden')
            ->add('transport', 'hidden')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Far\AssetManagerBundle\Entity\MovementNotification'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'far_assetmanagerbundle_movementnotification';
    }
}
```

ItemMovedType.php

```
<?php

namespace Far\AssetManagerBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Far\AssetManagerBundle\Entity\LocationRepository;
use Far\AssetManagerBundle\Entity\StateRepository;
use Far\AssetManagerBundle\Form\Type\ItemChoice;

class ItemMovedType extends AbstractType
{

    private $em;

    public function __construct($em, array $options = null)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder
            ->add('Item'
                //->addModelTransformer($transformer)
            )
            ->add("movementNotification", 'hidden')
            ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Far\AssetManagerBundle\Entity\ItemMoved',
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'far_assetmanagerbundle_item_movedtype';
    }
}
```

Entity\ItemMoved.php

```
<?php

namespace Far\AssetManagerBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * ItemMoved
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="far_assetmanager_movement_notification_item")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ItemMoved
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * Set id
     *
     * @param integer $id
     * @return ItemMoved
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @var \Far\AssetManagerBundle\Entity\Item
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Far\AssetManagerBundle\Entity\Item", inversedBy="items",cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="item_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $Item;

    public function setItem($item)
    {
        $this->Item = $item;
    }

    public function getItem()
    {
        return $this->Item;
    }

    /**
     * @var \Far\AssetManagerBundle\Entity\MovementNotification
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Far\AssetManagerBundle\Entity\MovementNotification")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="movement_notification_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     * })
     */
    private $MovementNotification;

    public function setMovementNotification($mn)
    {
        $this->MovementNotification = $mn;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getMovementNotification()
    {
        return $this->MovementNotification;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        if ($this->getItem() == null || $this->getMovementNotification() == null) {
            return "";
        } else {
            return $this->getItem()->getDescription() . " " . $this->getMovementNotification()->getId();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: show us the form type, the one to handle `MovementNotification` entity

Comment: also, the `$items` property in `MovementNotification` entity should be set as `Collection` of `ItemMoved`.

Comment: Ok, I added form type of MovementNotification

Comment: Also I'm getting the error "This form should not contain extra fields." in the form.

Comment: `$form   = $this->createCreateForm($entity);`  change to `$form   = $this->createForm($entity);`

Comment: Imanali, the signature for createForm does not match the one your trying to pass